# is there a way to use the keyword (this) more than once

Tags: jquery, this

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".title", this).click(function(){
      $(".content", this).slideToggle();
   });
});
```

code seems fine but it doesn't work. please help. thanks

Comment: Please provide your relevant HTML (preferably as code snipped) and describe what you want to happen and what happens instead.

Comment: i think it's pretty obvious in the given jquery code that there are multiple `.title` and `.content` classes. you click a certain title and a certain content triggers the `.slideToggle()` effect, but what happens is nothing happens when either one of the title is clicked

Comment: html code:`<div class="container">
        <div class="title">im a title</div>
        <div class="content">this is a text</div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="container">
        <div class="title">im another title</div>
        <div class="content">and another text</div>
     </div>`

Comment: Your jQuery code would work if the `.content` was a child of the clicked `.title`, but it's a sibling, so you would need something like `$(this).next().slideToggle();`.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add formatted HTML, don't add as a comment. It's relevant here as your code would work with `document >> .title >> .content` but you have `document >> .title + .container`.    Note that `this` in doc.ready isn't needed and you have just done `$(".title")`.

Comment: The better solution here would be to use an arrow function so that the inner (arrow) function retains `this` from the outer function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing the HTML shows the problem:
Your `content` DIV is not a child of `title` so the `$(".content", this)` returns and emtpy jQuery object. I suggest to use the `siblings()` function if you don't want to rearrange your HTML:
https://api.jquery.com/siblings/#siblings-selector

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".title", this).click(function() {
    console.log(this.tagName+" "+this.innerHTML);
    $(this).siblings(".content").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">im a title</div>
  <div class="content">this is a text</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">im another title</div>
  <div class="content">and another text</div>
</div>
```